# Simple solr query in order to search for a name in a field

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am trying to search for whatever docs which have for example Reddy and Kumar in the respondent_name field but whenever I tried this search I never get what I want.
I have tried it:

```
respondent_name:”Reddy Kumar”~3
/select?indent=on&q=respondent_name:%E2%80%9DReddy%20Kumar%E2%80%9D~3&rows=1000&wt=json
```

I did get result from this query but most of them returned for any docs which have Reddy and Kumar word in any field, not the docs which has these word in the respondent_name field.

I tried to follow this site but for some reason, it doesn't work for me:
https://dzone.com/articles/tips-name-search-solr

Json docs samples:

```
{
    "db_id":["590dd7e5fa25c3080f0d706e"],
    "main_title":["District Courts, Ananthapur"],
    "respondent_name":["Erikela Sunkanna",
      "The ManagerLegal CellICICI Lombard General Insurance Co.Ltd.",
      "S. Chandrasekhar Reddy"],
    "id":"9a3c1c41-a634-4df8-91e6-1a90072ebd9f",
    "_version_":1574199934804033536
},
{
    "db_id":["590dd7bbfa25c3080f0d6eb4"],
    "main_title":["Jr . Civil Courts,Uravakonda"],
    "respondent_name":["Nayika Chinnappayya",
      "Nayika Chinna Reddy",
      "Nayika Devi",
      "Nayika Gowramma"],
    "id":"65dff199-5e51-415e-9fa3-14693c74a6a9",
    "_version_":1574199931583856640
},
{
    "db_id":["590dd7d0fa25c3080f0d6f93"],
    "main_title":["Jr . Civil Courts,Tadipatri"],
    "respondent_name":["Y.Hari Kumar Reddy"],
    "id":"a162347b-6af1-4c1f-b65b-3eee76f71469",
    "_version_":1574199933688348672
}
```

Does anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us your schema.xml .

Comment: I couldn't find this file into my solr directory, but I am pretty sure that it is the default of a solr 6.6.0